# How can I get Jest to pickup my Kotlin-js tests?

Tags: jestjs, kotlin-js

By default, IntelliJ wants me to use Jest when running unit tests so, I've been trying to use it instead of QUnit which is our current testing framework.

When trying to run my JS project's tests with Jest, I get the following error `No tests found, exiting with code 1`. I have been following the instructions from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-unit-tests-on-jest.html and https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration. Have I set up my `package.json` file wrong? How can I get Jest to pickup my tests and any dependencies?

Do you use Jest as your testing framework for kotlin-js? If not, which framework do you use?

Comment: I use this for testing js             `testTask {
                useMocha()
            }`